# anaconda opencv python version different from anaconda python version

Tags: python, anaconda, opencv

(base) C:\Users\Aspire 5>python
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

(opencv) C:\Users\Aspire 5> python
Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Nov 13 2018, 17:33:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

how can i change python version in opencv env into the version as same as above??

Comment: You will probably simply need to (re)create the environment with the appropriate version of Python. From the [official docs](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html#managing-python), you can run e.g. `conda create --name opencv python=3.5`. Just substitute `3.5` with the version of Python you would like to run in the environment. You may need to run `conda deactivate` (if the `(opencv)` environment is active) as well as `conda env remove -n opencv` to remove the existing environment (alternatively `conda env remove -n opencv --all` to remove all dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

Activate the opencv environment.

Then you can run `conda install python==3.6` This *should* also resolve any dependencies of any modules installed that are set up for python 2.x

Side-note: You can downgrade python with the same command by substituting a lower version of python.